# Amazon S3 data usage and request counter

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-s3

Is there any way to get detailed info about how much requests done to my S3 bucket and how much space used by my files in bucket? I need it to watch whether or not I exceeded limits 
(in my case free usage tier). I want something precious like *"you've used 800 requests per 1000 available"*, so please do not refer to automatic billing alert emails or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

(Answer By @Frank)
You can enabble logging on the bucket and then use the API to figure out what is going on. You can also access your live usage figures in your AWS Account Console.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html

Answer (score 0):

This won't get you the exact real-time figures, but I needed to have an idea of how much I'm spending on the S3 `putObject` requests, and how those changed over time after I made some optimizations in my code, and this worked for me.

1. Launch the [Cost Explorer](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-reports/home?#/custom) and click <kbd>New Report</kbd>
2. Choose *Day* or *Month* on the top left and set the Time Range (7 days, 14 days, 3 months etc)
3. Filter by *Service* and select the one you're interested in (SNS, SQS or S3), don't forget to click *Apply*
4. Group your report by a dimension (API Operation, Instance type, Region etc.)
5. Save your report for future use